# Svelte.js, Video tag broken

Tags: html, html5-video, svelte, sveltekit

I have a video tag, only works in pc browser, Phone browsers it just shows the posters and stays still at  00:00 duration,.... i have the file extension [webm, ogv and mp4] none fixed it .

```
<div class="video">
            <center>
                <video src="/static/intro.mp4" autoplay loop muted playsinline id="myVideo"
                    controls
                    poster="https://sveltejs.github.io/assets/caminandes-llamigos.jpg"
                    on:touchmove|preventDefault={handleMove}
                    on:mousedown|preventDefault
                    on:mouseup|preventDefault
                    bind:currentTime={time}
                    bind:duration
                    bind:paused>
                      <track kind="captions"/>
                </video>
```

Comment: Have you tried it without Svelte? Chances are it has nothing to do with that.

Comment: Did you try without the `<center>`? Looks like that's deprecated and so might make problems https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center

Comment: @Beji What is your _"PC browser"_ and _"Phone browsers"_ exactly? Also is the video in H264 or HEVC picture format? Some browsers do not play HEVC inside MP4...